# How to hide measures on a Tableau filter

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Tableau chart and I've added a quick filter on Measure Names but this also adds a default measure name of 'Number of Records' to my list of measures.  I'd like to remove/hide this from the filter but not sure if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Number of Records is just a predefined calculated field created when you make a new data source.  You are free to hide it or rename it or even delete it.

Take a look at the definition of the field to see how it works.

Comment: This is correct, you can both delete it and recreate it if your choose.

Answer (score 0):

If this is Possible to hide the **Number of records** to right click the options are shown in hide or delete.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Simply convert the Number of Records to a Dimension.

Answer (score -2):

To my knowledge removing the Number of Records field from the filter isn't possible without deleting or hiding the field, which means you wouldn't be able to use it elsewhere. It's a trade off.